# Solve $(x+7)^2+\sqrt{y-8}=0$

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations, quadratics

I need help for solving the following equation :

> $$(x+7)^2+\sqrt{y-8}=0$$

I already got $(x=-7),(y=8)$ as the answer, but it isn't clear enough. A simple explanation or another solution would help me.

Comment: want you to solve this equation?

Comment: Technically, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x+7)^2=-\sqrt{y-8}$$

LHS $\ge 0$ and RHS $\le 0$

Equality occurs only when : LHS $=$ RHS $=0$

$$\implies x=-7 , y=8$$

Comment: yes and in the case $$x=-7,y=8$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Absolutely Correct!

Comment: $$(x+7)(x+7)=-\sqrt{y-8}$$$$(x+7)=0$$ $$x=-7$$So now $x = -7$, we put into the equation and it becomes $$0=\sqrt{y-8}$$Square both sides$$y-8=0$$ Then I got $y=8$ and $x=-7$. Thanks!